# dictionary of collocations

Tags: discussion, resources

I need a good dictionary of collocations. On Amazon I found these two:

1. MacMillan Collocations Dictionary
2. Oxford Collocations Dictionary for students of English

Which is better?

Do you know any other dictionary?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Oxford Collocation Dictionary http://www.freecollocation.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using corpora, some of which have excellent searching options once you learn their respective syntaxes.

I find [BYU corpora](https://corpus.byu.edu), though lacking in curb appeal, to be excellent for collocations. Downside: You may need to create an account and/or limit your number of queries per day unless you're willing to subscribe.